# set keywords into array

Tags: php

I'm using automatic php class to gets the keywords from my website page content
and the out put is exactly like

```
$text = "blah word1 blah word2 blah word3 blah"
$keywords = "word1, word2, word3";
```

[image: echo $keywords;]

and let suppose i've

```
$url = "http://www.some_site.com";
```

**Now** i've gonna convert all that keywords that inside my text content into links by adding those keywords into array as follow

```
$keyword_array = array(
"word1" => $url,
"word2" => $url,
"word3" => $url
);
```

The question now is how then to convert

```
$keywords = "word1, word2, word3";
```

into

```
$keyword_array = array(
"word1" => $url",
"word2" => $url,
"word3" => $url
);
```

since content and keywords indeed differ from page to page and can't do manually !

I've been thinking of using `explode` for `$keywords` but i don't know how to do it
any help ~ thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the URL is the same for all keywords:

```
$keywords = "word1, word2, word3";
$url = "your url goes here";

$keyarr = array_map('trim', explode(",", $keywords));
$keyarr = array_combine($keyarr, array_fill(0, count($keyarr), $url));
```

As an added bonus, this will work correctly regardless of the presence of spaces near the commas in the keyword list.

**[See it in action](http://ideone.com/stmMn)**.

Comment: ~ thanks a lot - the idea is very smart and i've added into my website and tested , works perfect :)

Answer (score 2):

```
foreach (explode(",", $keywords) as $keyword) {
    $keyword_array[trim($keyword)] = $url;
}
```